# Prism for Xamarin.Forms: I cannot resolve the navigationService unless if ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Have been stuck for days ... and then I found what was the issue

I have two pages one in case of tablet and the other in case of phone . Since they have different names then using ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel to share the same view model as a binding context does not work . So for this case I am using the classic binding context, as i did not want to create a viewmodel copy for each page. 
My problem was when I run it gives me an error saying "no parameterless constructor defined for this object prism" The reason of this error is that the viewModel has a contructor that expects a navigationService. 
To solve this error i have to remove the navigation service as an argument , but then I need it so i can navigate with it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would recommend using the ViewModelLocationProvider.Register method.  So in the application's RegisterTypes method, you can put a condition similar to this:

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register("MainPage", () => your logic);
else
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register("MainPage", () => your logic);
```

EDIT: Actually, you'll still have to manually resolve the INavigationService doing it this way.  I am going to reopen your Prism Issue.  We can look into improving the ViewModelocationProvider.Register method to enable this scenario.

Comment: Thanks man,  just to confirm about your your suggestion regarding having the same viewmodel , you mean by "your logic" in your code snippit , that it can return new MainPageViewModel()   ? 

And by manually you mean to pass the INavigationService through the constructors ?

Comment: yes, this is where you would return your instance of the ViewModel.  The problem is that you would still be responsible for creating the INavigationService and passing it into the ctor.  You can see what would need to be done here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L49

Comment: This is why we should improve the ViewModelLoctor to support registering types, not just instances.  I reopened your issue.  Could you please confirm the scenario and help me get this fixed for you?

Comment: I think you guys have answered me correctly there . Thanks ! you guys rock!